# Factorializing a number by creating an array and multiplying it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am going through one of the FreeCodeCamp challenges.

> " Return the factorial of the provided integer.
>
> If the integer is represented with the letter n, a factorial is the
>   product of all positive integers less than or equal to n.
>
> Factorials are often represented with the shorthand notation n!
>
> For example: 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120 "

I already know that the easiest way is to use recursion but by the moment I've discovered this fact I was already trying to solve the problem by creating an array, pushing numbers in it and multiplying them. However I got stuck on this step. I have created an array with the number of digits depending on the function factorialize argument, but I can't get the product of those digits. What did I do wrong:

```
function factorialize(num) {
  var array = [];
var product;
  for(i = 0; i<=num;i++) {
 array.push(i); 
for (j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
  product *= array[j];
}
return product;
 }
}
factorialize(5);
```

Comment: You are pushing `0` as the first element. So naturally the product will also be `0`.

Comment: Also you should initialize the `product` as `1`.

Comment: the point is that the function returns NaN, not even 0 :)

Comment: Check Adam's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42346845/3507137) below for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need initial value 'product' variable
2) You should change i = 0 to 1. You multiply by 0 in the loop
3) You don't need nested loop

```
function factorialize(num) {
  var array = [];
  var product = 1;
  for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    array.push(i); 
  }
  for (j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
    product *= array[j];
  }
  return product;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to create a range and reduce that:

```js
var n = 5;

function factorize(max) {
  return [...Array(max).keys()].reduce((a,b) => a * (b + 1), 1);
}

console.log(factorize(n));
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you missed a close parenthesis

```
function factorialize(num) {
  var array = [];
  var product = 1;
  for(i = 0; i<=num;i++) {
    array.push(i); 
  }                     //right here!!!    <----
  for (j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
    product *= array[j];
  }
  return product;
}

factorialize(5);
```

but as stated in the comments, you should change `i = 0` to `i = 1` not just because it would change the final result(which it does for all num ) but because it also doesn't follow the factorial algorithm.

Comment: sorry about that but where?

Comment: Extra closing bracket after `return product;` and `product` should be initialized with `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked now. I had 3 errors:

1. The closing parenthesis of the first for loop was after the return product instead of being after the array.push(i).
2.  I was pushing 0 as the first element so the product was always 0. Change i=0 to i=1 - fixed the problem.
3. I did not initialize product as 1.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop for that,
from 1 to the maximum number, then you multiply them up,
just a little clean up from your code
fact variable will contain the string version of the individual numbers making up the sum

if m is 5 you'll fact will be 1*2*3*4*5

```
function factorialize(num) {
  var product = 1;
  var fact = ""
  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    product *= i;
    fact += i + "*"
  }
  fact = fact.substring(0, fact.length - 1)
  console.log(fact) 
  return product;
}
console.log(factorialize(5));
```